# VBA find function on table array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows that do not contain a specific character in an array of a table column. The array loads the data just fine, but when trying to set "x" with the Find function I am getting "Object Required" and it is stumping me.

I am sure this simple, but every solution I have come across makes no difference in the outcome.

```
        srchRng = Range("OS[OS Version]")
        Set x = srchRng.Find(What:="=", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If x Is Nothing Then x.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: what variable type is x?

Comment: I haven't declared it specifically yet. Just testing and stepping through at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested** - Put it within a `With` block like this:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("OS[OS Version]")
    Set x = .Find(What:="=", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then x.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

---

Note that you are searching for cells that have an equals sign and nothing else.

Comment: Trying this now. I am trying to find cells that have that value in their string...

Comment: Then you would want to use a wild card rather than matching the whole string to this single character.

Comment: Ok, the With block worked, thank you! I tried using "What:="*=*" but that just deletes the first row, which has an "=" in it an no other rows in the sheet. (I'm still fairly new to VBA, as you can tell)

Comment: There are * on either side of the = inside the double quotes, but the website here removes those when I post the comment

Comment: From what I'm finding this should work for you: `.Find(What:="*=*", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: Well, that method is doing _something_ but not deleting what I want and x is being set to a single value rather than an array. I appreciate your knowledge and will keep plugging away at this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your If statement is backward.  Try this:

```
If Not (x Is Nothing) Then x.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: It does not make it to the If statement. I get "Object Required" on Set x.

Comment: Check that srchRng is getting set:  If srchRng Is Nothing Then MsgBox "SrchRng Is Nothing"

Comment: It is getting set just fine. 25K+ rows and the values are there. However, it is a table so the values are located at 1,1;2,1;3,1 etc

Comment: Scratch that, I get "Object Required" on If srchRng Is Nothing Then MsgBox "SrchRng Is Nothing", but the values are loaded into my Watch Window

Comment: Try assigning srchRng using 'Set' since it's an object.

Comment: Thanks Memetic, using Set worked on my original format, but I am still unable to get it to delete the proper rows. The if statement will delete row3(which doesn't meet the criteria) and then exit